# How to Use Count in Update Statement condition?

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql

We have two tables, Bucket and Student. We have to update Bucket_id in Student table having same country and city. But in my Bucket table I have two Bucket Ids against same country and city we can differentiate them by Desc.

When we update Bucket_id in Student table keep in mind when can only assign 70 students to same bucket Id. After 70 Students have been assigned, it will update with another bucket Id

```
Bucket Table
BucketId  Desc    Country  City
1         SOUTH    PAK     KHI
2         NORTH    PAK     KHI
```

Initially Bucket_Id in Student is null

Expected Result Below: After Update Bucket_Id in Student Table

```
  Student Table
  StudentId  Country  City  BucketId
  101           PAK     KHI   1
  102           PAK     KHI   1
  109           PAK     KHI   1
  201           PAK     KHI   2
```

I have tried using

```
update student std set Bucket_Id = (
select bucket_id from Bucket b where b.country=std.country and b.city = std.city and count(std.bucket_id) < 70
);
```

How can we do that? We are using oracle 11g.

Comment: You can do it easily using PLSQL block. If you want to do it using single query, could you please paste the expected result and what query you want to execute as an idea.

Comment: i have update my question. Initially Student Table is null After Update Query Student Table having bucket_id

Comment: This piece can be easily handled at application level

Answer (score 1):

You can assign the buckets using a query:

```
select s.*, b.bucketid
from (select s.*,
             row_number() over (partition by country, city order by studentid) - 1 as seqnum
      from students s
     ) s join
     (select b.*,
             row_number() over (partition by country, city order by bucketid) - 1 as seqnum
      from buckets b
     ) b
     on s.seqnum between b.seqnum * 70 and (b.seqnum + 1) * 70 - 1;
```

Oracle doesn't have very good support in `update` for handling updates across tables, so you then need to use `merge`:

```
merge into
    students s using
    (select s.*, b.bucketid
     from (select s.*,
                  row_number() over (partition by country, city order by studentid) - 1 as seqnum
           from students s
          ) s join
          (select b.*,
                  row_number() over (partition by country, city order by bucketid) - 1 as seqnum
           from buckets b
          ) b
          on s.seqnum between b.seqnum * 70 and (b.seqnum + 1) * 70 - 1
    ) ss
    on s.studentid = ss.studentid
when matched then update
    set s.bucketid = ss.bucketid;
```

Comment: sir i found this error SQL Error: ORA-00969: missing ON keyword once run your code please help

Comment: sir please read my question i have to update bucket_id in student table but for only 70 students i have update same bucket_id after 70 , it will update with another bucket_id having same country and city from bucket table

Comment: @abdulraheemdev . . . I understand the question and this answers it.  The `merge` looks correct to me.

Comment: sir i found this error ORA-30926: unable to get a stable set of rows in the source tables please help

Answer (score 0):

See if this works for you:

```
update students std set BucketId = (
select  min(bucketid) from Bucket b where b.country=std.country and b.city = std.city)
where bucketid is null
and std.STUDENTID in (
SELECT x.STUDENTID FROM 
(
select StudentId, 
  rank() over(partition by country, city order by StudentId) rn  
from students 
)  x where rn <= 3);
```

Comment: sir please read my question i have to update bucket_id in student table but for only 70 students i have update same bucket_id after 70 , it will update with another bucket_id having same country and city from bucket table

Answer (score 0):

You can also try this, if I understood the problem correctly:

```
MERGE INTO student t
USING (
SELECT
  studentid
, CAST( 
    ROW_NUMBER() OVER(
      PARTITION BY country,city 
      ORDER BY studentid
    ) / 70 + 0.5 
  AS NUMBER(9,0) 
  ) AS bucketid
FROM student
) s
  ON (t.studentid=s.studentid)
WHEN MATCHED THEN UPDATE
SET bucketid = s.bucketid
```

Comment: thanks for your reply but sir you did not use bucket table to get bucket_id i get error once run your code..

Comment: sir please read my question i have to update bucket_id in student table but for only 70 students i have update same bucket_id after 70 , it will update with another bucket_id having same country and city from bucket table

Comment: The above will set bucket_id to 1 for the first 70  student_id-s for , for example , PAK and KHI. The next 70 student-id-s will get a 2 for bucket_id. Is that not what you need?

Comment: get this error ORA-30926: unable to get a stable set of rows in the source tables

Comment: That means that you have at least once the same student_id in the same country and city. You will have to remove the duplicates before succeeding

Comment: great sir i can restrict to only 70 students can update not more than 70 student.